Does a US resident born in Mexico need a passport to visit Mexico?
I was born in Mexico and recently became a US resident. Do I need a US passport to travel to Mexico?

What proof do you have that you were born in Mexico?  Do you have a Mexican passport?

A US resident isn't entitled to a US passport. Did you become a US citizen?

Lots of US residents wouldn't qualify for a US passport.

If you were born in Mexico, you are a Mexican citizen.
You can enter Mexico with:

Mexican Passport
INE voter credential
Birth Certificate
Mexican Consular ID
Mexican Nationality Certificate

You can also enter with a foreign (like a US) passport as well.

You can re-enter the US with a passport + the appropriate visa/green card.

Technically, a passport is not required to enter the US if they have a green card.
